# Spring boot 1.x , How to increment a metric by an amount

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have an application built with spring boot 1.x and the whole process to expose metric is different from v2.x of spring boot.

Currently, I am using a cache in my application where i check for key existence in bulk and my requirement is that the counterService that increments a metric should increment it by some amount rather than by 1 so that I can leverage the bulk part atleast.

How do i achieve that?

One way i have done before is including Dropwizard metrics in spring boot. But I want to work under the scope of Spring boot actuators.

Answer (score 1):

You may just have to implement your own `CounterService` using the `DefaultCounterService` as a template: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.17.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/writer/DefaultCounterService.java

Then add methods something to the tune of `increment(String metricName, int delta)`.

Then register an instance of the bean in your configuration - and it'll override the `DefaultCounterService`.

You'll need to refer to the instance by your specific type name so you can access the methods you added.

Comment: Can i not use any pre-existing injectable writer that boot actuator provides.. I see  MetricWriter, JmXMetricWriter, CompositeMetricWriter, etc.

Comment: I see that the DefaultCounterService itself uses MetricWriter.